# atomic AddUint32 overflow

Tags: go, atomic, integer-overflow

I'm using the below code to get unique IDs within process:

```
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    go func() {
        for {
            atomic.AddUint32(&counter, 1)
            time.Sleep(time.Millisecond)
        }
    }()
}
```

What will happen if the counter value overflows uint32's limit?

Comment: See "Integer overflow" in the spec: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Arithmetic_operators

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value wraps around, which is very easy to demonstrate:

```
u := uint32(math.MaxUint32)
fmt.Println(u)
u++
fmt.Println(u)


// or
u = math.MaxUint32
atomic.AddUint32(&u, 1)
fmt.Println(u)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/lCOM3nMYNc

Comment: Hi, yes thats i found out myself. I thought there might be some bottlenecks or so in the scenario. Thanks anyway! Just wanted to be confirmed...